# an array, and a variable to display as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, variables

I'm using jquery and have two arrays with the names, `question0AnswerTextArray` and `question1AnswerTextArray`.

Inside these arrays are strings `["text for answer 1", "text for answer 2"]`

I also have a variable named `quizQuestion`.

I'm trying to get text to display like below:

```
var tempBoxText = 'question'+quizQuestion+'AnswerTextArray['+answerNumber+']'; 
$('#quizTextBox').text(tempBoxText);
```

Any ideas? Or are multidimensional arrays possible in JavaScript/jQuery?

Thanks for suggestions..I just started JavaScript recently.

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, a better way would be to use an array of  arrays:

```
var answers = [
    ["text for answer 1", "text for answer 2"],
    ["text for answer 1", "text for answer 2"]
];

$('#quizTextBox').text(answers[quizQuestion][answerNumber]);
```

I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Thank you for such quick responses!  This help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimensional arrays are possible in JavaScript. Setting them up is a little different (but is just an array of arrays), and the syntax for retrieving values is like:

```
var val = myArray[x][y];
```

`x` and `y` can be your question and answer indices.